# Adding a "box" to latex document with different style than the rest

Tags: boxes, moderncv

I have my CV written using Latex, using `moderncv` document class. I really like the output, but at the bottom of the CV I need to put a disclaimer (required in Poland), which doesn't really fit into any of the predefined CV items. It should just be paragraph, using the same font as the rest of the CV, but otherwise normal Latex style. How can I do it?

If I just paste the text at the bottom, it is aligned to the right, whereas I need it aligned to the left and ideally justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't supplied a test file but probably

```
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{% or whatever
some words here
}}
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: This looks good, cheers! Would it be possible to put this box at the bottom of the current page automatically?

Comment: @Grzenio put a blank line then `\vspace*{\fill}` before the box, probably.